# Detect headphones in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, directsound, naudio, headphones

I'm trying to detect if the headphones are plugged in on Windows. I've already tried DirectSound and the NAudio library and have not had any success. Does anyone have any suggestions?

NOTE: this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in), but the answer to that question didn't contain any code samples or tutorials.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in That question isn't tagged for Windows, but Larry Osterman is a Microsoft software engineer who's worked on the audio subsystem for years so he knows what he's talking about. He doesn't reference any samples or tutorials of how to do this, so I'm still interested to see if anybody digs anything up in response to this question.

Comment: please pardon my edit of your question, but I wanted to make sure it isn't closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Are you trying to detect analog headphones plugged into the line-out jack of a soundcard or USB headphones?  That will heavily influence my answer.

Comment: @selbie: only analog.. But I think I find the answer..

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872895/detect-if-headphones-are-plugged-in-or-not-via-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

So...I think I might found something REALY obscure..

Can any of you guys check if that works? - You MUST have the **[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)** library referenced..

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var d = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
Console.WriteLine(d.Properties[new Guid("46d16a2c-5654-41c0-911e-7860d2bce7ee")].Value.ToString());
```

This property return's 1 (Plugged) or 0 (Unplugged).. and It's working realy good for me..

**UPDATE**: Just published the app on [CodePlex - iTunesHead](http://ituneshead.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I have tried running this project on my PC and that particular GUID does not seem to exist (Null reference), so I think it depends on hardware/drivers. I also tried comparing all the device properties before/after plugging and unplugging headphones and nothing changes.

Comment: Yeah..that was what I was thinking when I found this GUID, must be a thing only on my Dell, so I kinda drop this project after that..

Answer (score -1):

What about [Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.Speakers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809296.aspx)?

> A Speakers object should have one of the following speaker type properties set to true:
>
> - FivePointOne
> - Headphone
> - Mono
> - Quad
> - SevenPointOne
> - Stereo
> - Surround

Comment: All the prop's retun the same value. I keep plugging/unplugging the headphones, all stay the same..


HeadPhone: False
FivePointOne: False
Mono: False
Quad: False
SevenPointOne: False
Stereo: True
Surround: False

Comment: Only other refs I could find are: <http://www.mp3car.com/coders-corner/88344-windows-speaker-setup.html> and <http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/DirectSound9p1.aspx>