# Jack Sensing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, io, microphone

I am writing an application that will record audio from microphone. My problem is I need to know when the user plug in the jack and remove the jack out.

I looked into `Win32_SoundDevice` WMI class and seems to me there is no such a property that I can check the status of the Jack.

Then I found `RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback` in `IMMDeviceEnumerator` which seems to do what I need but I have no clue how to do this in C#. Does anyone know how to use `MMDeviceEnumerator` methods to check for audio port status ? Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at then open source [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) project.

I've browsed their code and it appears they have a .Net wrapper for your [`IMMDeviceEnumerator` interface](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/294f957710dd#NAudio/CoreAudioApi/Interfaces/IMMDeviceEnumerator.cs).

As this project is under Microsoft Public License, it'll probably be usable in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check out with following code:

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var d = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
Console.WriteLine(d.Properties[new Guid("46d16a2c-5654-41c0-911e-7860d2bce7ee")].Value.ToString());
```

This property return's 1 (Plugged) or 0 (Unplugged)..

You must have the NAudio library referenced..

Comment: I am getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in the Guid, what is the guid ?

Comment: This sounds like a copypaste of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5527467/5994170