# On headphones connection

Tags: windows

I want to know when headphones are plugged into my computer, as well as change the volume of Windows. I know how to change the volume but I have no idea how to catch that event. When I plug in headphones, Windows asks me if  headphones or a microphone has been plugged in, so an event has occurred (or at least that what I think that happen).

The only two things that came up in my mind are:

1. Check if headphones are connected all the time, but headphones are not a device.
2. Hook that event, I don't think I can hook that type of things

How can I know if headphones have been connected? I have no idea what I even have to search for. What ideas do you guys have?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect headphones in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526998/detect-headphones-in-windows)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting when head phones are plugged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in)