# Check to see if ear phones are in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, audio, vb.net-2010

Is there a way to check if earphones are in(vb.net)?

I'm using vb.net 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect headphones in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526998/detect-headphones-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872895/detect-if-headphones-are-plugged-in-or-not-via-c-sharp). The solution is in C# but I'm sure you can find a way to implement it into your project.

You might also want to take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/829712/Managed-Wrapper-around-MMAudioDeviceApi

Comment: Looking for the same but unfortunately this didnt work on Windows 10 21H1.