# Is it possible to detect whether or not something is plugged into the audio jack, in python?

Tags: python, audio, windows-7, headphones

I'm trying to detect if there is a device hooked into the audio jack with python. This is in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://superuser.com/questions/110933/how-does-a-sound-card-determine-if-headphones-are-plugged-in

The answer is: It depends on your hardware. I have not seen any operating system detect headphones in the past decade, but some cheap soundcards do support it. (edit: According to Larry Osterman's comment, they are now standard.)

If your soundcard supports it, I believe you will find the following to be the answer you are looking for: [Detecting when head phones are plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in) (python will probably need to ask some system API)

Comment: Windows Vista and above have done this.  And every audio solution sold with a Windows Vista or above logo is required to support jack detection.  So I'm not totally sure I understand why you say "I havae not seen any operating system detect headphones in the past decade".  Jack detection has been a part of Windows for the past half decade.