# Line-in jack sense with C/C++ in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, events, audio

This has probably been asked to death around here, but I could never get to a final solution (probably for good cause).

Anyway, is there any way in Ubuntu (I use Ubuntu 11.04 with kernel 2.6.38-8) to detect if there is a headphone plugged in? Specifically, I'm searching for C/C++ solutions to poll my ALSA device to detect if a headphone device has been plugged in.

Of all the threads I searched, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in) deals only with Windows, and I couldn't figure out if [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23508/how-to-automatically-change-volume-level-when-un-plugging-headphones) provides a proper solution (there was no change whether the headphones were plugged in or not).

Ok, looong post, but I'd really appreciate the help.

Cheers,
Karthik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jack detection API is ([here](https://dri.freedesktop.org/docs/drm/sound/kernel-api/alsa-driver-api.html) or [here](https://dri.freedesktop.org/docs/drm/sound/kernel-api/writing-an-alsa-driver.html)):

```
snd_jack_new — Create a new jack
snd_jack_set_parent — Set the parent device for a jack
snd_jack_report — Report the current status of a jack
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your link and from there started reading up on the ALSA API. I'll post any successes here, in case anybody else has the same requirements I do

Comment: I am working with same things to detect headphone jack but not able to access this link.Could you guys provide another link which shows jack detection API ? @BЈовић

Comment: @raj123 Thanks. Fixed dead links.

Comment: I go through it,so its for kernel level API not application lever right?So using this I need to write kernel driver to detect jack right?@BЈовић