# Detect microphone/headset?

Tags: audio, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

is it possible in Mango to detect if a headset is connected or not? I want to update some UI elements depending if the user has connected a headset or not. (what i really need is the microphone from the headset)

Thanks for advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting when head phones are plugged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in)

Comment: @AShelly No, the other question is not about Windows Phone 7 but normal Windows OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API available to provide this information.
You won't be able to make this distinction in your app.