# How can i detect that something is plugged in to the audio jack with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to do this in vb.net? I've searched everywhere but cant find any answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it depends on hardware - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in

Answer (score 0):

You can use endpoint device events
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370810%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Sample code is only in C# but you can use any of the many C# to VB.NET code conversion tools to figure it out.