# Detect external device connect to head phone jack

Tags: php, jquery, .net

Can you please help me I want to make a Mobile Website page which give me details of the external device details connect to the USB drive or head phone jack also whether the device is connected or not.

Please suggest me.

Comment: So which is it?  PHP? .NET?  jQuery?

Comment: How did this get an upvote? You cannot realistically use any of the suggested languages/frameworks for this. Also, define "device"?

Comment: Next to never if never was next to the blackhole of neverness. Mobile phone companies are strict with hardware stuff as it is and on top of that a mobile website? On the internet? Accessing hardware information? Major security issues there.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in However – detecting headphones on a mobile site, is as already said, next to impossible. In WP7 for instance, you can't even detect it for native apps.

Answer (score 6):

From a web-page? You can't.

Ask yourself: when have you ever seen this done. The answer is most likely "never", because you can't get that from javascript. A full java client might be able to, but: on a "Mobile Website" (which I interpret to mean: a web-site that works on mobile) that is next-to-never available.

You need a new design.

Also: frankly, I don't **want** your web-page looking at my USB ports.

Comment: A VA feeding the trolls? My, you *are* in a charitable mood today... :-P

Comment: What you hiding in your USB ports? ;)

Comment: @Lix well, "the source code for SE" would spring to mind...

Comment: Actually I want to make a mobile web application which use a swiper to swipe card. I bought an IDtech Shuttle card reader which provide sdk to read. But I want a some driver which get installed according to the mobile device so that my web page can read the card number when the card is swipe from Idtech Shuttle.

Comment: @VishnuGupta you're probably going to need a native app to use that

Comment: You keep the source on usb drives? I thought all the code was kept deep within the bowls of an Icelandic mountain range only accessed every other Friday to push  pluralization bug fixes... guess I was wrong :P