# Get automatically notified on audio device connection/disconnection?

Tags: delphi, audio, notifications, delphi-xe2, device

Is it possible to get automatically notified whenever the user connects or disconnects an audio device?

Comment: If you meant un/plugging USB-based audio device, then yes. Use `WM_DEVICECHANGE` window message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/861601/10396 may have some useful info.

Comment: Jay: I fear, that when using WM_DEVICECHANGE, this could exclude audio devices using another interface.

Answer (score 3):

In Vista+ you can use Core Audio [IMMNotificationClient interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be notified.

> The IMMNotificationClient interface provides notifications when an
>   audio endpoint device is added or removed, when the state or
>   properties of an endpoint device change, or when there is a change in
>   the default role assigned to an endpoint device.

Handling `WM_DEVICECHANGE` and/or polling is the solution in odler OS versions.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! Does anybody know how to implement the IMMNotificationClient interface in Delphi, to be notified when audio devices are connected or disconnected? Thank you!

Comment: The MSDN article explains it step by step, and conversion to Delphi - as far as I know - is rather straightforward. You create enumerator, register for notifications and eventually receive them.

Answer (score 1):

To receive notifications for Audio Devices plug and unplug, please follow these steps:

1. Derive class from IMMNotificationClient interface using this msdn link:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
2. Create Device Enumeration Object using this msdn link:
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/610aacff-062e-4453-8437-01f0de038b07/jack-detection-for-headset

In the 2nd step repalce line 
IMMNotificationClient *pNotify = NULL;

with 
IMMNotificationClient *pNotify = new CMMNotificationClient;

With this implementation all you will receive all plug, unplug notification in CMMNotificationClient's overloaded functions.

Please make sure to delete CMMNotificationClient at end :)