# Way to get notification about audio device enable/disable in Windows XP/7/8

Tags: windows, winapi, audio

Is there way in Windows API to be notified when audio device gets enabled or disabled?

I have source code with RegisterDeviceNotification() and WM_DEVICECHANGE; it tracks USB device insertion/removing good. But it does not track laptop's internal audio device enabling or disabling.

Of course I can make timer and use waveInGetNumDevs/waveOutGetNumDevs.
But it is more interest to find way to force OS to send notifications :)

Thank you :)

Comment: You're probably enabling/disabling the audio device via audio control instead of from Device Manager. They are different.

Comment: Yes. I'd get notification if I disable audio in Device Manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`waveIn`/`waveOut` is legacy API you don't have notifications with. Yes you can poll with timer, of course, as you mentioned. In Vista+ the newer API does have notifications via [IMMNotificationClient interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), see also this related answer: [Get automatically notified on audio device connection/disconnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899658/get-automatically-notified-on-audio-device-connection-disconnection)