# Detect if headphones are plugged into the headphone jack in Java

Tags: java, audio, headphones

Is there a way to detect in Java if headphones have been plugged into the headphone jack? This solution must be specific to Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting when head phones are plugged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson - Not a duplicate.  The other question is facially more general.  And the answers are all Windows specific, and not a good answer for Java.  (The OP does not ask for a Java "solution" that only works on Windows ...)

Comment: Afaik there are no decent cross platform solutions. I see your point though.

Comment: I suspect this isn’t possible.  For me, `AudioSystem.getSourceLineInfo(Port.Info.HEADPHONE)` returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Before Vista there was no way of determining that information but there is a way to detect it in windows vista and beyond, use of mmdevapi.dll via executing rundll32.exe
for running exe files, use RunTime class. in java.
for further information about that take a look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx